# Is it possible to use an integer stored in a variable to serve as the decimals of a float?

Tags: python, variables

Is it possible to use an integer stored in a variable to serve as the decimals of a float?

The below code of course won't work, but it is added to demonstrate the concept.

a = 5

b = 1.a

Comment: `b = 1 + (a / 10)`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in a way.

Just use
b = 1 + (a / 10)

Comment: This won't work if a has more than one digit

Comment: Unless the OP wants it to work with more than one digit. We just don't know enough from the OP. 

If the OP wants the entire "a" value to be the decimal. We can add a loop to handle each place value. Hopefully the OP clarifies his need in case "a" is more than just 0-9 integers.

Comment: That's why it's recommended not to answer unclear questions until they are clarified ;)

Comment: Cunningham's theory says a wrong answer improves engagement and gets to the right answer faster.  I think the OP is happy to see this answer AND the string-based answer and they can now see the vagueness in what they thought was a perfectly clear question.